# nextJs proxy timeout after 5 seconds

Tags: next.js

My front-end is in react.ts(nextJs version - 13.4.9) and the backend spring boot.

One of our clients makes an API call to the front-end and the front-end passes the the request to the backend using rewrites().

However, I get the following error only after five seconds.
Does anyone know why it is happening and how I can fix it?

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:721:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:468:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

I have been looking for a way to set the timeout from the nextjs document on rewrites(). I could not find anything about timeout.